# Entity Framework cannot find stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have an application that I am updating. I've added a stored procedure to the database, tested it and it is working.

I then updated the ADO model in the application. The stored procedure is showing in the server browser and in the Model.Store in the Model browser. Intellisence picked up the name when I created a method to use the new stored procedure. I can run the stored procedure from Visual Studio.

When I run the application, however, I get this error:

> SqlException: Could not find stored procedure.

I'm using Entity Framework 6.0, and the project runs on .NET 4.5.2

The code per a comment request.  Note:  Code is identical to other methods that are currently working.  The only difference is this is dealing with a new stored procedure in the database.

```
public TransactionReport TransactionReportSingle(long TransID, long 
AgencyID)
    
        TransactionReport result = null;

        using(ECCustomEntities dc = new ECCustomEntities()) {
            var objectResult = dc.spGetReptInfoByTransID(TransID, 
AgencyID);

            if(!objectResult.Equals(String.Empty) && !(objectResult 
== null))
                foreach(var item in objectResult) {
                    result = new TransactionReport() {
                        TransID = item.TransactionID,
                        CNumber = item.Number,
                        CaseID = item.CaseID,
                        SubmittedOn = item.CreatedOn,
                        Name = item.Name,
                        OName = item.OName,
                        Comment = item.Comment,
                        StatusDescription = 
item.TransactionStatusTypeName,
                        Agency = item.Description
                    };
                    break;
                }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Where is code which executes stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

So after thinking smart didn't solve the problem, I started thinking stupid.  After building a new project and trying the method, I ended up getting some other errors that led me to upgrading the EF to the latest version.  (The new project had 6.2 and the latest is 6.4.4).

So I deleted EF from the project that I was updating (it was already at version 6.4.4) and reinstalled.  It's working now.  Not sure what that did but it's something to try if you are stuck.